# Is it possible to have the menu link color change on the table hover for an asp.net menu control?

Tags: css, asp.net

I'm using an ASP.net menu and when i hover inside my menu item's table, i change the background color on the table column, but unless i hover over the link text itself, the link text color will not change.

Is it possible to have the link text color changed on the table hover?

Example below shows what happens.

[image: example of issue]

Excuse the ugly CSS:

```
.TopStaticSelectedStyle
{
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: Verdana;
}

.TopStaticMenuStyle a,
.TopStaticMenuStyle a:visited,
.TopStaticMenuStyle a:active
{
    color: #ffffff;     
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Verdana;
}
.TopStaticMenuStyle a:hover 
{
    color: #000000;     
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 11px;        
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family:  Verdana;  
}

.TopStaticMenuItemStyle td
{       
    padding: 0px 12px 0px 12px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #6c85b0;
    height: 18px;
    border-top: solid 1px #012754;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #012754;
    border-left: solid 1px #012754;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.TopStaticHoverStyle
{
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: Verdana;
}

.TopStaticHoverStyle td
{
    padding: 0px 12px 0px 12px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height: 18px;
    border-top: solid 1px #012754;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #012754;
    border-left: solid 1px #012754;
        border-collapse:collapse;
        color: #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I scrapped your css and just started from scratch but you should be able to get the idea from [this](http://jsfiddle.net/2xdwJ/2/).

So some basic table html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#">Test</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#">Test 2</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>​
```

And then the css:

```
a {
    color:#000;
}
td {
    border:solid 1px black;
    background:#234567;
    padding:5px 10px;
}
td:hover {
    background:#eee;
}
td:hover a {
    color:#ccc;
}
td a:hover {
    color:#777;
}
​
```

The key here is the `td:hover a` selector which is what you need to change the color on hover of the `td`.

Comment: Another method is to make the `a` tag `display: block;` and do all the color switching on that.  Shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/2xdwJ/3/

Comment: BOOMSHAKALAKA!! John, you nailed it. Thanks! Matthew, i tried your method but the asp.net menu was being a bit buggy about it. I see it does work in your example though